# Caractere inválido em arquivo .bat

Tags: windows, batch, cmd

Senhores !

Tenho um arquivo .bat que utilizo para iniciar o Apache Tomcat da minha aplicação em modo de debug. Porém ao executar este arquivo no CMD, a primeiro coisa exibida é a seguinte mensagem:

**'´╗┐' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.**

Ressalto que após isto, o script funciona normalmente, porém gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por algo semelhante ou conhece alguma solução. Eu havia tentado refazer o mesmo, porém o erro persiste.

Segue abaixo o conteúdo do arquivo:

```
@echo off

echo.

rd /s /q C:\tomcat\work\
rd /s /q C:\tomcat\conf\Catalina\
del /s /q C:\tomcat\logs\*
del /s /q C:\tomcat\temp\*
del /s /q C:\tomcat\webapps\sa\WEB-INF\web.xml.template
del /s /q C:\tomcat\webapps\sa\META-INF\context.xml.template

echo.

set CATALINA_HOME=C:\tomcat
set CATALINA_BASE=C:\tomcat
set JAVA_HOME=C:\java\jdk7
set INSTANCE=C:\instance

set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 

set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Djava.awt.headless=false
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9014
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Duser.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Duser.language=pt
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Duser.region=BR
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xdebug 
set CATALINA_OPTS=%CATALINA_OPTS% -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8990,server=y,suspend=n

%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
```

Comment: Tem certeza que é esse bat e não o startup.bat? Se você copiar o conteúdo desse bat tal como esta aqui e salvar em outro arquivo bat  e executa-lo o erro também ocorre?

Comment: Oi Reginaldo ! O problema está neste .bat provavelmente, pois o erro é exibido na tela antes da primeira ação do script e a chamada do startup é o último passo. Ressalto que sim, tentei recriar o .bat conforme tua sugestão e o erro persistiu. Obrigado !

Comment: Salvar o arquivo com padrão ANSI, e teste.

Answer (score 4):

O seu arquivo possivelmente foi salvo com UTF-8 **COM** `BOM` (BOM sendo a abreviação de BYTE ORDER MARK) no bloco de notas, ou seja no topo do documento `.bat` ou qualquer tipo de documento, quando é salvo com **UTF-8 BOM** é adicionado um caractere chamado **byte-order mark**, que já foi citado em algumas perguntas aqui no site, mais detalhes sobre o BOM em utf-8 e outros como utf-32 em:

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte

Basicamente o seu .bat pensa que esse caractere chamado **byte-order mark** é um comando, no caso o caractere unicode `U+FEFF` é imprimido como `´╗┐`, o .bat procura então um programa com tal nome, o que provavelmente não existe, ocasionando assim o erro de comando ou programa não reconhecido.

Criei um exemplo salvando em UTF-8 via Bloco de Notas do Windows:

```
@echo off

echo Oi

pause
```

No caso deixei uma linha antes do `@echo off` e logo ao executar ocorreu o mesmo erro:

[image: erro]

Veja que é o mesmo caractere `´╗┐`

---

Se deseja usar UTF-8 você deve salvar com UTF-8 sem BOM ou usar ANSI (ou qualquer formato compatível), vai depender da necessidade.

Se desejar ainda sim usar UTF-8 você deverá fazer uso de um programa mais avançado, como notepad++ que pode ser baixado em:

- https://notepad-plus-plus.org

Abra o seu .bat nele e salve assim:

> [image: utf8 sem bom]

Se utf-8 não for necessário para ti no proprio bloco de notas do windows selecione **Salvar como...** e selecione ANSI:

> [image: ANSI]

Answer (score 1):

Possivelmente seu problema não esteja no batch, mas na página de caractere usada no sistema na pela interface do prompt/cli, sugiro dar uma verificada nas configurações das chaves:

```cmd
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
OEMCP="850"
```

Verifique se figura algo diferente de **850** ou **1252**, caso esteja outro valor, é só mudar 850, ou 1252

Para verificar na linha de comando, use:

```cmd
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" | findstr "OEMCP"

rem :: o comando retorna a saída assim :: OEMCP    REG_SZ    850
```

Para alterar usando a linha de comando você pode usar o comando abaixo, observando que necessário executar como administrado:

```cmd
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage" /v OEMCP /t reg_sz /d 850 /f
```

Já tive problemas quando precisava da exibição de um caractere que figurava no chcp 65001, após eu mudar o valor na chave, retornando para o padrão chcp 850, meus batchs pararam de exibir essa mesma mensagem com estes caracteres..

tem post que me ajudaram: 
[esse foi 1](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)
[esse foi outro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432545/change-codepage-in-cmd-permanently)